# Trying to display image encoded in base64

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, base64

I'm trying to display my image (encoded in base64) on my browser.

This is what I had tried:

```
        {{$projects}}
        <hr>
        @foreach ($projects as $project)
            @if ($project['name'] != null)
                <p>Project {{ $project['name'] }}</p>
                <img src="data:image/{{$project['image_type']}};base64,{{$project['image']}}" alt="Project picture" >
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

Which looks like this on the browser link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jeZB.png

Unfortunately that didn't work out.

Before displaying an image. I had uploaded an image to my database with the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    if($request['file'] != null) {
        $file = $request['file'];
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $imageType = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    } else {
        $fileName = null;
        $imageType = null;
    }
    Project::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
        'image' => base64_encode($fileName),
        'image_type' => $imageType,
    ]);

    return redirect('/projects');
}
```

Can someone maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're encoding the filename in database and not the file contents.

Read about http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

```
(...)
'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileName)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Niloct is right.

Insted of

```
base64_encode($fileName);
```

you must use

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileName));
```